# New-Object : Cannot find type [Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag]

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using `New-EC2Tag` to create/update the EC2 tags through Azure Pipeline. I am using "**AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script**" task and below is the code:

```
$Tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag  
$Tag.Key = "DesiredInstanceState"  
$Tag.Value = "Stopped"

New-EC2Tag -Resource $instanceName -Tag $Tag
```

When the task runs I get below error:

> 2020-06-16T18:40:57.4642775Z ##[error]New-Object : Cannot find type
>   [Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag]: verify that the assembly containing this type
>   is loaded. At
>   C:\1_work_temp\d2378116-3224-4a4a-b92c-61744a291aac.ps1:2 char:8
>   + $Tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>   2020-06-16T18:40:57.4655375Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

I installed the module on both the build server and the server for which I am trying to create the tag, still the same.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Explicitly import the module before creating the object, ie. `Import-Module AWSPowerShell`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it worked like a charm. I tried installing the module but i guess import is the right way.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Mathias in the comments, I updated the script to include `Import-Module -name AWSPowerShell` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with creating DateInterval for AWS costexplorer, tried:

```
Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell -force -SkipPublisherCheck

Import-Module -Name AWSPowerShell
```

Works as expected.